# Interaction factor (RCT trial)

Tags: statistical-significance, interaction

How could you explain that during a trial (RCT), some features may have no interactions between them if you consider them as categoric features, but have an interaction if you consider them as continuous features ?
Thank you !

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean by "have no interactions." Does that just mean that the interaction term isn't statistically significant if you include it as a predictor in the model? Or does it mean something else? Adding a simple, reproducible example or a literature reference would help a lot. Please provide that information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Artificially dichotimizing variables decreases power. This is true for main effects, and for interactions. The difference in your findings is due to this decrease in power.

Here's an example where power is 83% when $X_1$ and $X_2$ are continuous:

```
> library(InteractionPoweR)
> power_interaction(n.iter = 10000,N = 800,r.x1.y = .2,r.x2.y = .2,r.x1x2.y = .1,r.x1.x2 = .1)
Performing 10000 simulations
    N    pwr
1 800 0.8309
```

Power becomes 45% when they are both artificially dichotomized:

```
> power_interaction(n.iter = 10000,N = 800,r.x1.y = .2,r.x2.y = .2,r.x1x2.y = .1,r.x1.x2 = .1,k.x1 = 2,k.x2 = 2,adjust.correlations = F)
Performing 10000 simulations
    N    pwr
1 800 0.4449
```

Comment: Could also easily see the opposite if the relationship is non-linear.